# Generate near tables from one layer to all in mxd

Tags: arcpy, layers, mxd, proximity, iteration

I am looking to create a script where user can choose a layer, then find all the layers within a set distance of it. I have set up a script to iterate through the mxd but I keep getting an error for the Generate Near Tables line saying my parameters are invalid and that my value is not a feature layer. I even added in a line to convert all to feature layers but this error won't go away. is it something wrong with my loop or input classes? I am new to coding so this is very overwhelming. This is the code I have been working with:

```
import arcpy
import sys

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0] 
ctr1 = 1
ctr2 = 1

destPath = r"E:/File_Organization/Data/Working_Folder" 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers
# Output layer to shapefile
    outLyr = sys.argv[1]
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr, outLyr) 
    for outLyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):
        inFc = sys.argv[2]
        outT = sys.argv[3]
        distance = sys.argv[4]
        outL = sys.argv[5]
        outTable = outT + str(ctr1)
        FinalLyr = outL + str(ctr2)

        arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(inFc, outLyr, outTable, distance, "LOCATION", "NO_ANGLE", "ALL", "", "GEODESIC")
        ctr1 = ctr1+1
        arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(outTable, "NEAR_X", "NEAR_Y", FinalLyr)
        ctr2 = ctr2+1
```

Comment: you say you want the user to choose 1 layer, but then it looks like you are looping through all of the layers in the map. sys.argv[2] will be the same everytime through the loop.

Comment: That is what I am looking to do. I want to generate near tables from all features to one input layer. I may have gotten something but it still isn't quite what I was looking for.

Comment: What is the full text of the error message that you receive, including line number, when you run the precise code that you have presented?